# Automatically change UITextField when reach determine length

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

Hi I have 3 `UITextFields` and I want to change automatically to the next `textfield` when the user enters 3 characters. I manage to limit the length of one of the `textfields` that has a normal keyboard input, for the other 2 that have a numeric keypad I could limit the length.

Here is what I have for one of the `textfield` to limit the length:

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

{

```
if (dia.text.length >= 2 && range.length == 0)
{
    [self.mes becomeFirstResponder]; // esto activa el siguiente textfield
    return NO;
}

if(mes.text.length >= 3 && range.length == 0) {
    [self.anio becomeFirstResponder]; // esto activa el siguiente textfield
    return NO;
}

if (anio.text.length >= 4 && range.length == 0)
{
    [self.hora becomeFirstResponder]; // esto activa el siguiente textfield
    return NO;
}

if (hora.text.length >= 2 && range.length == 0)
{
    [self.minutos becomeFirstResponder]; // esto activa el siguiente textfield
    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

}

EDIT: on viewDidLoad I have this 5 lines if I remove them the limit doesn't work on anyone but if I leave them I only can input text on just one text field:

```
self.dia.delegate = self;
self.mes.delegate = self;
self.anio.delegate = self;
self.hora.delegate = self;
self.minutos.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the firstResponder.

```
if(mes.text.length >= 3 && range.length == 0) {
   [textField resignFirstResponder]; // this will dismiss the keyboard from the current textfield
   [self.theOtherTextfield becomeFirstResponder]; // this will activate the desired textfield
}
```

**UPDATE**

In your viewDidLoad add this:

```
self.dia.tag = 1;
self.mes.tag = 2;
self.anio.tag = 3;
self.hora.tag = 4;
self.minutos.tag = 5;
```

and then the new `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is:

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

if (dia.text.length >= 2 && range.length == 0 && textField.tag == 1)
{
    [self.mes becomeFirstResponder]; // esto activa el siguiente textfield
    return NO;
}

if(mes.text.length >= 3 && range.length == 0 && textField.tag == 2) {
    [self.anio becomeFirstResponder]; // esto activa el siguiente textfield
    return NO;
}

if (anio.text.length >= 4 && range.length == 0 && textField.tag == 3)
{
    [self.hora becomeFirstResponder]; // esto activa el siguiente textfield
    return NO;
}

if (hora.text.length >= 2 && range.length == 0 && textField.tag == 4)
{
    [self.minutos becomeFirstResponder]; // esto activa el siguiente textfield
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to call `resignFirstResponder` on the current text field. Just call `becomeFirstResponder` on the next one.

Comment: @notme works great for the one that has the default keyboard but for the ones with the number pad the lenght limit doesn't work

Comment: Is the delegate correct? Is the shouldChangeCharactersInRange fired?

Comment: yes thats the one I am using, I update the code on the question.

Comment: So what happen exactly? Which property has the wrong value? Has the if statement fired correctly?

Comment: the first one works great, the other 3 didn't work, those are the ones with numeric keypad.

Comment: ok, silly me: how do you get to the second if statement if your function return YES before it? Return YES should be at the very end of your function and should be fired only if all other if statements are false.

Comment: @notme found a posible error on the code on viewDidLoad I put it on the original question.

Comment: The delegate is right, but you are not checking whatever textfield is currently active. After the first textfield has reach its max length, the first if statement would be always true (dia.text.length will return 2, whatever textfield is active). You can add a tag to each textfield to check that you are monitoring the length of the textfield that is currently being edited. I have added some code for a better explanation.